# How customary are for European governments to sell government bonds online directly to individuals?

Tags: european-union, government-bonds, eur-euro, online-tools

The State Treasury (under the helm of the Ministry of Finance (and not the Central bank as it is sometimes in the other countries)) issues the government bonds for the Republic of Latvia and in the form of savings bonds everyone can purchase them in the retail manner directly from the government website https://www.krajobligacijas.lv/ without involving bank services or other intermediaries (aside from making the payment, of course) that can provide custody services. In such manner the financial transaction fees and other commissions can be avoided. I have also seen the similar website for the US Treasury bonds.

But what about other European countries - do at least some of them provide such online services for the retail purchase of government bonds? I tried to google some countries but without success. E.g. there are explicit warnings that it is very hard to purchase the Greece bonds even for serious investors and one should never dream about services for individual buyers. I am also interested in the similar services for bonds issued by the pan-European financial institutions like European Stability Mechanism, European Investment Bank or Fund.

One side note - (at least for Latvia) it is not possible to convert such savings bonds in the usual tradable financial instruments, that is some drawback of such online services, but early redeem is possible with some small losses. But that is fine for me, that there are some constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a community wiki so everybody who has information can answer here:

- Spain allows it: https://www.tesoropublico.gob.es/es/servicios/compra-y-venta-de-valores